# Insert sorted input text box from checkbox selections

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem where I need to be able to dynamically insert new search fields in a list - sorted by a particular order as defined in the HTML5 data attribute.

If I have this simple HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Personel</td>
    <td>Region</td>
    <td>Misc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' data-sort='3'> Name<br />
        <input type='checkbox' data-sort='4'> Gender
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' data-sort='1'> Country
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' data-sort='2'> Parent
    </td>      
</tr>
</table>
```

It will result in this simple layout with three columns:

[image]

if I then click on for example **Name** it should add an `input` text field:

[image]

If I then add for example the **Country** field it should add this field BEFORE the **Name** due to the sorting attribute:

[image]

And if all fields were visible:

[image]

Of course going the other way around, unchecking the checkboxes, it should remove the search field.
I have this Fiddler with the simple code, http://jsfiddle.net/kEnye/

Can anyone give a hint on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Personel</td>
                <td>Region</td>
                <td>Misc</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign='top' width='100'>
                    <input type='checkbox' data-sort='3' checked='checked'> Name<br />
                    <input type='checkbox' data-sort='4' checked='checked'> Gender
                </td>
                <td valign='top' width='100'>
                    <input type='checkbox' data-sort='1' checked='checked'> Country
                </td>
                <td valign='top' width='100'>
                    <input type='checkbox' data-sort='2' checked='checked'> Parent
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />

        <input type='text'data-sort="1" size='7' value='Country'> <input type='text' size='7' data-sort="2" value='Parent'> <input type='text' size='7' value='Name' data-sort="3"> <input type='text' size='7' value='Gender' data-sort="4">
            <script>
    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){

            if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
            {
            $('input:text[data-sort="'+$(this).attr('data-sort')+'"]').hide();
            }
            else{

                 $('input:text[data-sort="'+$(this).attr('data-sort')+'"]').show();
            }
        });
</script>
```

Try this. It is going to work

Comment: This one works fine with me. I have updated the Fiddler demo here, http://jsfiddle.net/kEnye/4/

Answer (score 0):

You add a class name to the search fields.

```
<input type='text' class="search-field" size='7' value='Country' >
```

Initially you hide all searchfields and as you select/unselect the checkboxes you append/remove (jQuery functions `append()`/`prepend()` and `remove()`) the search fields.

When a checkbox is selected you check the sort attribute of each of the elements from the checked checkboxes.

```
$('input:checked[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){console.log($(this).data('sort'));});
```

If any of them has larger sort attribute value then you may append the new search field before the search field corresponding to this checkbox. Otherwise if none of the checkboxes has larger sort value, then you simply append your search field.

In order to find the corresponding search field, which is also useful to call when you uncheck a checkbox, you need to search all search fields with value the same as the *value* of the checked/unchecked checkbox.

```
//where this is the checked/unchecked checkbox

     $('input.search-field[value="Name"]')
```

For this to work it would be nice to add a *value* attribute to each of your checkboxes corresponding to the value attribute of your search fields.

If you want i can prepare a working solution.